# wifi соединение c++

Tags: c++, linux, wifi

Есть ли стандартные средства, или библиотеки для работы с wifi подключением. Простое сканирование сетей, занесение их допустим в список, и подключение/отключение. Также интересна литература на счет работы wifi.

Comment: Средства работы с WiFi не входят в стандарт C++.

Comment: Уточни операционную систему.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow но существуют же какие либо библиотеки написанные под данные нужды ?

Comment: @АнтонСазонов интересует linux

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Я думаю, что несомненно существуют где-нибудь в проектах с открытым кодом.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow http://habrahabr.ru/post/76888/ нашел таки хоть какое то упоминание

Comment: @ParanoidPanda  Можно еще прозондировать сайты производителей оборудования для WiFi. Они также могут предоставлять соответствующие библиотеки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

стандартных средств, как правильно написали в комментариях, конечно, нет.

зато есть, например, [wireless extension](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/Tools.html) — *api*, позволяющий *wifi*-драйверам предоставлять интерфейс для управления, конфигурации и получения статистики от беспроводных устройств.

примеры использования можно увидеть в *wireless tools*, которые находятся на этом же сайте, а также в [различных программах](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/Tools.html#links), использующих *wireless extension*.

Answer (score 2):

У NetworkManager есть API для обращения к нему через DBUS.

Из плюсов - возможность обратиться к нему из любого окружения вроде Python или Qt